# MySQL Select Query: SUM() rows with a distinct value, from another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a lot of trouble with this SQL select query. I'm starting to believe I will need to make temporary table of some kind, but I'm probably wrong.

I need to show which products identified by P_CODE sold more than the average product on this table. The problem I'm facing is that there are multiple entries with the same P_CODE.

```
SELECT LINE.P_CODE FROM LINE
WHERE LINE.LINE_UNITS > (SELECT SUM(LINE.LINE_UNITS) FROM LINE)/(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LINE.P_CODE) FROM LINE);
```

This select query takes me close to the desired result, but I actually want to run the following:

```
SELECT LINE.P_CODE FROM LINE
WHERE (SELECT SUM(LINE.LINE_UNITS) FROM LINE GROUP BY LINE.P_CODE) > (SELECT SUM(LINE.LINE_UNITS) FROM LINE)/(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT LINE.P_CODE) FROM LINE);
```

but I receive this error

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

I'm sorry if my presentation of the table is poor, I took a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OckOK.png) of it as well. But I'm including it to help explain why I can't use the AVG() function.

---

`LINE_UNITS     |   P_CODE
1   |   13-Q2/P2
5   |   13-Q2/P2
2   |   13-Q2/P2
1   |   1546-QQ2
1   |   2232/QTY
1   |   2238/QPD
1   |   23109-HB
2   |   23109-HB
1   |   23109-HB
1   |   23109-HB
2   |   54778-2T
3   |   54778-2T
1   |   54778-2T
1   |   89-WRE-Q
12  |   PVC23DRT
5   |   PVC23DRT
3   |   SM-18277
3   |   WR3/TT3`

Comment: `Mysql` <> `Sql Server` choose the one you are using !!

Comment: Which database are you using.Please use the Tag properly @Pivot

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I'm using mysql, I fixed the tags a little while ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If am not wrong you are looking for something like this

```
SELECT l.P_CODE
FROM   LINE l
GROUP  BY l.P_CODE
HAVING Sum(l.LINE_UNITS) > (SELECT Sum(LINE_UNITS) / Count(DISTINCT P_CODE)
                            FROM   LINE)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much, I was not familiar with the HAVING clause yet.